# c - dynamically allocate variable names

Tags: c

I am trying to take number of inputs from a user and take the inputs then and store them under dynamically created variable names. can anyone help?
I want to take the number of array user want to input then create the exact number of variables which maintains a common pattern so I can know which array is under which variable and I can call them for further processing.

My current code is as follows

```
 int input, eqn, m, i,n,x;  
    char inputarr[100], eqnarr[100];  
    printf("Enter number of variables: ");  
    scanf("%d",&n);  
    m=n;  
    printf("Enter your variables: \n");  
    while(n!=-1){  
    gets(inputarr[n]);  
    n--;  
    }  
    while(m!=0){  
    puts(inputarr[m]);  
    printf("\n");  
    m--;  
    }
```

my inputs are like
2 (here 2 is number of inputs user intended to give)
a = 3
b = 4

I need to save them  in 2 variables say var1 and var2 as I need to work with them later.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically created variable names"? Also, what is the exact problem you are facing? Nothing is clear is from your question.

Comment: I want to take the number of array user want to input then create the exact number of variables which maintains a common pattern so I can know which array is under which variable and I can call them for further processing.
I am editing question now.

Answer (score 1):

C does not support dynamically created variables. You can instantiate dynamic objects through calls to malloc(), but these will not be named. In C, names are just labels used to associate names to memory locations at compile time, and resolved at link time. It is way too late at run time.

You can create a mapping from names to int values, but you cannot create new variables. A Mapping will work for you. You need to create a method to add a named value to your mapping, a method to retrieve the value, a method to update its value, and for completeness, you need a fourth method to delete an element when you no longer need it.

Here is a simple example of mapping variable names to int values using a dynamic lookup table. To be complete, you would need to add methods for updating values, and deleting them, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_VARIABLES 100

typedef struct Lookup_Entry_Struct {
           char* Name;
           int   Value;
        } LookUp_Entry;

typedef struct Mapping_Struct {
           int   MaxEntries;
           int   NumEntries;
           LookUp_Entry* mapping;
        } Mapping;

void initMapping(Mapping* map, int MaxEntries)
{
 map->NumEntries = 0;
 map->MaxEntries = MaxEntries;
 map->mapping = calloc(sizeof(LookUp_Entry), MaxEntries);

 if (map->mapping == NULL) {
    // Failed to allocate the Mapping table
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to alloc Mapping table of %d entries\n", MaxEntries);
    map->MaxEntries = 0;
 }
}


bool addMap(Mapping* map, char* Name, int Val)
{
 bool Added = false;

 if (map->NumEntries < map->MaxEntries) {
    // There is still room in the table, add this new variable
    LookUp_Entry* newEntry = &(map->mapping[map->NumEntries]);
    newEntry->Value = Val;
    newEntry->Name  = malloc(strlen(Name)+1);
    strcpy(newEntry->Name, Name);
    map->NumEntries++;
    Added = true;
 }

 return Added;
}


int lookup(Mapping* map, char* Name)
{
 int  val   = -1;
 int  i     = 0;
 bool Found = false;


 // Search the map to see if we can find Name
 for(i=0; i < map->NumEntries && !Found; i++)
   {
    LookUp_Entry* entry = &(map->mapping[i]);
    if (strcmp(entry->Name, Name) == 0) {
       // Found a match, return the value in *Val
       val   = entry->Value;
       Found = true;
    }
   }

 if (!Found)
    fprintf(stderr, "lookup of \"%s\" not found in map\n", Name);

 // Found value, or -1 if not found
 return val;
}

void getVariablesFromUser(Mapping* map)
{
 #define MAXNAMELEN  100
 // Code modified from Buno's sample
 int  NumVariables = 0;
 int  i;

 char inputName[100];
 int  inputVal;

 while ((NumVariables<1) || (NumVariables > MAX_VARIABLES)) {
    printf("Enter number of variables: ");
    scanf("%d", &NumVariables);
    if (NumVariables<0 || NumVariables>MAX_VARIABLES)
       fprintf(stderr, "Please enter no more than %d variables!\n", MAX_VARIABLES);
 }

 printf("Init mapping for %d variables\n", NumVariables);
 initMapping(map, NumVariables);

 for(i=0; i<NumVariables; i++) {
    printf("Enter variable #%d name and initial value: ", i+1);
    scanf("%s %d", &(inputName[0]), &inputVal);
    printf("Adding variable %s with initial value %d\n", inputName, inputVal);
    addMap(map, inputName, inputVal);

 }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 Mapping myVarMap;
 char*   varName;
 int     i;

 getVariablesFromUser(&myVarMap);

 // Display all the variables to show how to retrieve values
 printf("%d variables added by user\n", myVarMap.NumEntries);
 for(i=0; i<myVarMap.NumEntries; i++) {
    LookUp_Entry *entry =  &(myVarMap.mapping[i]);
    char*         name  = entry->Name;
    printf("Entry #%d: %s = %d\n", i+1, name, lookup(&myVarMap,name));
 }
}
```

Save this in file lookup.c, then to compile it:

```
gcc lookup.c -o lookup
```

Here is sample run:

```
scott> lookup
Enter number of variables: 3
Init mapping for 3 variables
Enter variable #1 name and initial value: Bob 123
Adding variable Bob with initial value 123
Enter variable #2 name and initial value: Ted 999
Adding variable Ted with initial value 999
Enter variable #3 name and initial value: Sally 0
Adding variable Sally with initial value 0
3 variables added by user
Entry #1: Bob = 123
Entry #2: Ted = 999
Entry #3: Sally = 0
scott>
```

Comment: I want to take the number of array user want to input then create the exact number of variables which maintains a common pattern so I can know which array is under which variable and I can call them for further processing.

I might not made that clear in the question. Now I edited though.

Comment: You do not need to create new named variables (which is impossible in C), but you can create a dynamic lookup table, where you can store names and  values. I have updated my response.

Comment: @Buno: I have added a simple example of a dynamic look up table that maps variable names to int values. Function addMap() adds mappings from C strings to int values, and lookup() retrieves the values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create variable names dynamically, however you can dynamically allocate memory using a function called 'malloc()'. You need to first understand pointers and then learn how to create and access memory during run-time.

Comment: I want to take the number of array user want to input then create the exact number of variables which maintains a common pattern so I can know which array is under which variable and I can call them for further processing.

I might not made that clear in the question. Now I edited though.

Comment: You are still not clear. Are you trying to create array of arrays. Please describe with an example, how your data looks like.

Comment: my inputs are like:       
2 (here 2 is number of inputs user intended to give)  
a = 3  
b = 4  
  
I need to save them  in 2 variables say var1 and var2 as I need to work with them later.

Comment: @Buno: You cannot create variables at run time.  What you *can* do is store names to a separate array, then create some kind of data structure to map those name entries to other arrays or objects.

Comment: @JohnBode the problem is that, I don't know how many inputs the user wants to give. so, this option is not best I guess. But I will use it if I am close to deadline but couldn't solve it. thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @JohnBode is ryt..please do some research on dynamic allocation..that will definitely solve your problem..First watch this entire playlist: [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2_aWCzGMAwLZp6LMUKI3cc7pgGsasm2_) Then watch this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDVC3wKjS64)

Comment: @Buno - it actually sounds like you need to implement an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) data structure; your "variable name" would be the *key*, and your other data would be the *value*.  You'd probably use a binary tree, where each node in the tree contains a name pointer (`char *`) and your data pointer (`void *` if you need to be able to store different types in each node).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments and answers of others, you cannot dynamically create variables in C.

However, you can follow this approach:

- Dynamically read the characters for each line of n expressions (When the
  length of input string is not fixed) For ex, Consider n =1 and the
  input line is "a=10" Read each character 'a', '=' , '1' , '0'
- Parse the string "a=10" to obtain the value 10. Dynamically allocate
  memory to store this value 10.
- Do this for all n input lines.

---

Here is the code to achieve this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Dynamically read the input string character by character: Taken from a SO answer
char *inputString(FILE* fp, size_t size){
//The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional
    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
    if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n'){
        str[len++]=ch;
        if(len==size){
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));
            if(!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++]='\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}

int main(void) {
    int n,i,numindex;
    char *variableline,*vartemp;
    char keys[] = "1234567890";

    //Read in the number of variables
    printf("Enter n\n");
    scanf("%d\n",&n);

    printf("Enter %d lines\n",n);
    //Allocate memory for these variables
    int *variable_values = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        // Read the characters dynamically from the n input lines
        variableline = inputString(stdin, 10);

        //numindex - index where the number starts. For ex, in the string "a=12", numindex is the position of '1'
        numindex = strcspn (variableline,keys);

        //Read the number into vartemp
        vartemp = malloc(strlen(variableline));
        strncpy(vartemp, variableline+numindex, strlen(variableline) - numindex);

        //Convert the string to number
        *(variable_values+i) = atoi(vartemp);
    }

    printf("The variable values are:\n");
    // All the variable values are stored in the dynamically created memory variable_values
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d\n",variable_values[i]);
    return 0;
}
```